# Rails Controller: Alert on Redirect Displays Text But Not Error String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I'm trying to render an object's error messages as a flash alert on redirect using the following code.

The code works - but only if I hard code a string into the field. It does not, however, work when I try to render `@order.errors.full_messages.to_sentence` (note: the errors render properly in the console log).

I've tried to assign the messages to a variable and render that variable, but to no avail.

This is the code I'm trying to get to work:

`redirect_back(fallback_location: event_path(@order.event), alert: @order.errors.full_messages.to_sentence)`

(note `puts @order.errors.full_messages.to_sentence` correctly displays the error messages in the console).

Here's an example of the hard-coded alert message, which works fine:

`redirect_back(fallback_location: event_path(@order.event), alert: "This alert works fine")`

Comment: Alert value is evaluated after redirect, I suppose, but in the events#show @order has already no errors

Comment: Thanks @Vasilisa - I suspected that might be the case, so I (hackishly) tried assigning the alert values as a string to a variable and then attach that string to the alert... Still, didn't work.